# Zend Framework 2 - BjyAuthorize always denies access

Tags: zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I have setup the [`bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/) module, but I am currently getting a `403` "access denied" error for each URL except for the one configured in the `home` route.

My `module.byjauthorize.global.php` looks like following:

```php
'bjyauthorize' => array(
    'guards' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest','user')),
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'stuff', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array()),
            //backend
            array('controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index', 'roles' => array('admin')),
            array('controller' => 'MyModule\MyEntity\MyEntity', 'roles' => array('admin')),

        ),

        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route' => array(
            array('route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => array('guest')),                
            array('route' => 'home', 'roles' => array('admin')),
            array('route' => 'my-entity', 'roles' => array('admin')),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I tried deleting the `BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route` part, but with no effect.
When I remove the `home` route then the homepage is also blocked.
So both Controller- and Route-Guard seem to work.
How can I debug this behavior?

Comment: Is the default role `guest` set?

Comment: yes. in the config and in the database (manually)

Comment: Hmm, the error in such can be pretty deep. This is a working config on my end, but im not guarding routes or controllers: https://github.com/manuakasam/DuitMarketplace/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L92  the controllers `index` and `Application\Controller\Index` are definitely different ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***NOTE***: following is valid for [BjyAuthorize `1.2.*`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/tree/1.2.1)

First of all, consider that protecting both the routes and the controllers is unnecessary. I personally always protect the controllers only, since there may be multiple routes to a same controller.

Once you removed either the route or the controller guard's config, you can:

- Install [Zend Developer Tools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools), which allows you to have an overview of the currently set [Acl role](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html#roles), like in this picture:

  [image]
- Check if you have configured the correct identity provider: the default one uses [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser)'s user id and looks up his role in the `user_role` table.
- Check that the `guest` role has access to the public pages, such as the `zfcuser` controller (for login actions) or the `zfcuser/login` route.

As Akrabat pointed out, the configuration for the `BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller` and `BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route` are [whitelists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist), which basically means that you have to setup access for the default `guest` role if you want to browse pages being un-authenticated.

As soon as a guard is configured, it blocks access to any not configured resource, so be sure that you have granted the role `guest` (or whatever you configured in `$config['bjyauthorize']['default_role']` access at least the login controller or route.

Comment: thanks you two! I made a mistake with the path to the controllers... so dumb! afaik until now it all seems to work!

Comment: @Ron even though your mistake is a typo, I've edited the question so that it is not too localized (otherwise it will be closed). I hope this is useful to others too :)

Comment: @Ocramius is there a way to make my api module bypass the authorization provided by bjyauthorize since my api module has it own authorization process?

Comment: Be careful of other modules over-writing the config.
In my case there was zfcadmin setting the bjyauthorise config and this caused issues with ROUTE Guard vs CONTROLLER guard. i.e. check all your config files for BJY integration and automatic configs

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you create one entry in the `'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller'` array, then you need to create entries for every controller with permissions as appropriate.

I have this:

```php
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
    // Access for everyone
    array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('guest')),
    array('controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest')),
    array('controller' => 'error', 'roles' => array('guest')),

    // Restricted
    array('controller' => 'User\Controller\AdminUser', 'roles' => array('admin')),

),
```

It's important that you give guest access to zfuser (for logging in!) and error (hard to debug stuff otherwise).

I've not tried using controller and route guards simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

I think the problem is that BjyAuthorize is not well documented so many of us are simply copying and pasting and working out from the files provided. For instance from the following:

```
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array()),
        ),
```

You would expect to add your controllers as such:

```
array('controller' => 'controllername', 'role' => array()),
```

However you need to add the full path otherwise it will not work:

```
array('controller' => 'Folder/Controller/Action', 'role' => array()),
```

I hope this saves someone a few hours work as I was totally befuddled by this!

Answer (score 0):

debug your code by this in module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
    {   echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($e->getTarget()->getServiceManager()->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface'));
    }
```