# Use 'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' and 'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route'

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I use the '*BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller*', which have all my `Controllers` and `Actions`.

- Do I need to use '*BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route*'?
- If this is necessary, what routes I have to use?
- It is clear that each route depends on action, or am I wrong?

So, why I need use '*BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route*', if all rules are defined in '*BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller*'?

I will be grateful for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Necessary and best practice are not the same thing. A lot depends on the complexity of your application and what you are trying to accomplish. I have read many just using BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller as there may be more than one route going to a controller.  If your routing is not very complex this would be the way to go in my opinion.

See this answer: [Zend Framework 2 - BjyAuthorize always denies access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343640/zend-framework-2-bjyauthorize-always-denies-access)